# Record and not added into the database using Php ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am creating the simple crud system using php ajax.in the crud system i add the image also.but when i fill the data and browse image and click add button record is not added in to the database.what i tried so far i attached below.no error shown on the console.i think might be the problem with jquery 
send the form values and images **data: {form_data: form_data,data: data},**

**Form Design**

```
 <form role="form" id="frmcompany" class="card" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div align="left">
            <h3>Company</h3>
        </div>

        <div align="left">
            <label class="form-label">Company name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Patient No" id="cno" name="cno" size="30px" required>
        </div>

        <div align="left">
            <label class="form-label">Country</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Patient Name" id="coutry" name="coutry" size="30px" required>
        </div>

        <div align="left">
            <label class="form-label">Currency</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" id="currency" name="currency" size="30px" required>
        </div>

        <div align="left">
            <label class="form-label">Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" id="address" name="address" size="30px" required>
        </div>
            <div align="left">
                <div class="fileuploader fileuploader-theme-default">
                    <input type="hidden" name="fileuploader-list-files_" value="[]">
                    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" >
                    <div class="fileuploader-items">
                        <ul class="fileuploader-items-list"></ul>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </br>

        <div align="right">
            <button type="button" id="save" class="btn btn-info" onclick="addPatient()">Add</button>
            <button type="button" id="clear" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>

        </div>


    </form>
```

**jquery**

```
            function addPatient()
{
    var upload_date = $('#file').prop('files')[0];
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('file', upload_date);


    if($("#frmcompany").valid())
    {
        var url = '';
        var data = '';
        var method = '';

        if(isNew == true)
        {
            url = 'php/add_patient.php';
            data = $('#frmcompany').serialize() ;
            method = 'POST';
        }


        $.ajax({
                type : method,
                url : url,
                dataType : 'JSON',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
               // data:  data,

            data: {form_data: form_data,data: data},

            success:function(data)
            {




                    if (isNew == true) {
                        alert("Company Addedd");
                    }



            }

        });

    }

}
$('#file').fileuploader
({
    limit: 1,
});

            <div align="right">
                <button type="button" id="save" class="btn btn-info" onclick="addPatient()">Add</button>
                <button type="button" id="clear" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>

            </div>

        </form>
```

**php code**

```
<?php

$servername = "***";
$username = "***";
$password = "***";
$dbname = "***";
$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

if($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("connection failed" . $conn->connect_error);
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{

   if (0 < $_FILES['file']['error'])
    {
        echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
    }
    else
   {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
   }

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into company(companyname,coutry,currency,address,image) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$companyname,$coutry,$currency,$address,$image);
    $companyname = $_POST['cno'];
    $coutry = $_POST['coutry'];
    $currency =  $_POST['currency'];
    $address =  $_POST['address'];
    $image = $_FILES['file']['name'];

    if($stmt->execute())
    {
        echo 1;
    }
    else
    {
        echo 0;
    }
$stmt->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: `data: {form_data: form_data,data: data},` will give in php `$_POST["form_data"]` and `$_POST["data"]`

Comment: You do `$stmt->bind_param("ssss",$companyname,$coutry,$currency,$address,$image);` and **after** `$companyname = $_POST['cno'];` and so on... Your variables are not set when you are binding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: You have a `success` member, but no `error` one to check is inserting failed.

Comment: What is `IsNew` ?

Comment: sir i created the variable  var Isnew = true

Comment: @Your I feel that the "mysqli" tag should be added back, since there is an issue with the prepared statement. Look at it again and you will see it. Unless you feel that this (typo) is "php" related and not "mysqli"?

Comment: @Cid `. Your variables are not set when you are binding` - it's OK

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner May be I am overlooking something but there is nothing to indicate there is a problem with mysqli. As far as I can tell it's a problem with javascript

Comment: @YourCommonSense Look at `VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)` and the number of `s`'s in the binding ;-)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thank you I see now. So technically yes, but given tags are for the question re-use and there are no answers related to mysqli, this tag will be misleading for anyone having a problem with mysqli. Let's agree on just closing the question :)

Comment: You're welcome @YourCommonSense :) and yes I agree.

Comment: no. i got the answer successfully below

Comment: @YourCommonSense is it ?

Comment: yes ..........see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send a `FormData` object inside another object. All the POST parameters have to be in `form_data`.

```js
function addPatient() {
  if ($("#frmcompany").valid()) {
    var url = '';
    var data = '';
    var method = '';
    var form_data = new FormData(document.getElementById("frmcompany"));
    var upload_date = $('#file').prop('files')[0];
    form_data.append('file', upload_date);

    if (isNew == true) {
      url = 'php/add_patient.php';
      data = $('#frmcompany').serialize();
      method = 'POST';
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: method,
      url: url,
      dataType: 'JSON',
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      data: form_data,
      success: function(data) {
        if (isNew == true) {
          alert("Company Addedd");
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: sir your one is working record is added into the database. why sir my browse image is not passing to the upload folder pls check sir thanks

Comment: What does `var_dump($_FILES)` show?

Comment: not shown anything sir at the console

Comment: You have to go to the Network tab of DevTools to see the debugging output.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function addPatient()
{
    var upload_date = $('#file').prop('files')[0];
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('file', upload_date);

      $.ajax({
            url: 'php/add_patient.php',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: `form_data` doesn't have any of the other form fields.